# Shopify request middleware

Tags: shopify, middleware

I want to know, is it possible to add a middleware or request interceptor to Shopify?

Something similar to express, to add some custom behavior or set any values between the request and the response.

I want to read some values from the request object and take some decisions and send that to the response.

Any guide or documentation for this.

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to supply some more details about what you want to intercept. There are various techniques to alter Shopify's standard behaviour depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

You can customize a Shopify theme using Liquid, their templating language. Liquid [has a `{{ request }}` object](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/request) which contains the path and domain of the request. You could adjust the body of the response based on that but it isn't like Express middleware.

Some people host their own website and use Shopify's [buy buttons](https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/buy-button) or [JS buy SDK](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/js-buy-sdk). If you do that then you can use Express if you want.